# How to make Electron automatically open downloaded files in external application?

Tags: javascript, pdf, electron, docx

I am building an Electron app with HTML and Javascript. I want the app to open downloaded files e.g. PDFs, DOCXs etc. automatically in the external standard application like Adobe Reader and Word. Is there a simple Javascript function to achieve this or maybe a better way? Right now Electron opens the download dialog, like in Chrome. I unfortunately don't have a lot of experience with Javascript, so I apologize if this is a too simple question for you to pay attention to.

```
const electron = require ('electron');
const url = require('url');
const path = require('path');

// In the main process.
const { app, Menu, BrowserWindow ,  shell } = require('electron')




// Listen for the app to be ready

app.on('ready', function() {
    // Create new window
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({});
    // Load html into window
    mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true
    }));

    // Build menu from template
    const mainMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(mainMenuTemplate);
    // Insert menu
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(mainMenu);

    mainWindow.webContents.session.on('will-download', (event, item, webContents) => {
        // Set the save path, making Electron not to prompt a save dialog.
        item.setSavePath('/tmp/save.pdf')// get the filename from item object and provide here according to your logic

      item.on('updated', (event, state) => {
        if (state === 'interrupted') {
          console.log('Download is interrupted but can be resumed')
        } else if (state === 'progressing') {
          if (item.isPaused()) {
            console.log('Download is paused')
          } else {
            console.log(`Received bytes: ${item.getReceivedBytes()}`)
          }
        }
      })
      item.once('done', (event, state) => {
        if (state === 'completed') {
          console.log('Download successfully')
          //Open the document using the external application
          shell.openItem(item.getSavePath());
        } else {
          console.log(`Download failed: ${state}`)
        }
      })
    })
});

// Create menu template 
const mainMenuTemplate = [
    {
        label: 'File',
        submenu: [
            {
                label: 'Quit',
                accelerator: process.platform == 'darwin' ? 'Command+Q' : 'Ctrl+Q',
                click(){
                    app.quit();
                }
            }
        ],

    },
    {
        label: 'View',
        submenu: [
            {
                label: 'Toggle Fullscreen',
                click(){
                    mainWindow.isFullScreen() == true ? mainWindow.setFullScreen(false) : mainWindow.setFullScreen(true)
                }

            }


        ],


    }

];

function toggleFullScreen() {

    mainWindow.setFullScreen(true) ?   mainWindow.setFullScreen(false) :   mainWindow.setFullScreen(true)

  }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can intercept the downloads using will-download event and show the downloaded file using shell.openItem();

```
// In the main process.

const {app, BrowserWindow, Menu ,shell } = electron;

app.on('ready', function() {
    // Create new window
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({});
    // Load html into window
    mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true
    }));

    // Build menu from template
    const mainMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(mainMenuTemplate);
    // Insert menu
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(mainMenu);
mainWindow.webContents.session.on('will-download', (event, item, webContents) => {
    // Set the save path, making Electron not to prompt a save dialog.
    item.setSavePath('/tmp/save.pdf')// get the filename from item object and provide here according to your loic

  item.on('updated', (event, state) => {
    if (state === 'interrupted') {
      console.log('Download is interrupted but can be resumed')
    } else if (state === 'progressing') {
      if (item.isPaused()) {
        console.log('Download is paused')
      } else {
        console.log(`Received bytes: ${item.getReceivedBytes()}`)
      }
    }
  })
  item.once('done', (event, state) => {
    if (state === 'completed') {
      console.log('Download successfully')
      //Open the document using the external application
      shell.openItem(item.getSavePath());
    } else {
      console.log(`Download failed: ${state}`)
    }
  })
})

});
```

https://electronjs.org/docs/api/shell

https://electronjs.org/docs/api/download-item

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! Can I just insert this code in my main.js without further modification?

Comment: I think yes, but make sure mainWindow and things fit to your code. also dont forget to modify the item.setSavePath()

Comment: So I tried to make a function called openDownloadedFile() of the code, since it does not compile, when I just insert it into main.js. How do I call the function now? I am only familiar with C and Java. Is something like 

```
if(download dialog appears) {
    openDownloadedFile()
}
```
possible?

I am currently doing a Javascript tutorial on Codeacademy, so I will hopefully make progress here soon!

Comment: you dont have to put it inside a function. paste the code after you create the window in main.js

Comment: What do you mean by "after you create the window in main.js"? The application doesn't start, when I insert it at the bottom.

Comment: please paste your code in main.js, we have a main process and renderer process, right. you have to put the code in the main process where you create new BrowserWindow();

Comment: So you mean paste it into the app.on('ready', function() or mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({}); ?

I have just built this following a tutorial, so I don't really understand fully what these functions do, sorry! I also tried changing "win" to "mainWindow", since it was declared twice, but then other errors emerge.

Comment: I made the changes in the answer, please have a look

Comment: I got it to run meanwhile and changed the code in the question accordingly, but when I try to download something, I get the message " "/tmp/save.pdf" could not be found. Make sure you entered the name correctly and repeat the process". Tried it with PDFs and DOCXs. I need to specify PDFs and all Office document types. Is the code correct like this? the const electron at line 1, is never used it says.

Your changes to the code did not start the application. Might be that I inserted it at the wrong place, though.

Comment: Just saw you wrote to get the filename from item object. Not sure how to do this! I need to do this for ca. 700 different filenames.

Comment: Try to use item.getFilename();

Comment: Tried         item.setSavePath('/tmp' + item.getFilename()) , but now it complains that the file is not found, but it downloads and is in the location. "C:/tmp/" does also not work.

Comment: Try path.join(app.getPath('userData') , item.getFilename())

Comment: Works flawlessly! Thank you so much! :))